# Fetching tenant specific APIs through Rest call

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have WSO2 2.1.0 setup and created a tenant named "xyz.com". I am able to create public APIs for this tenant and those are visible in store portal too. But I am trying to get those through Rest call(Rest call doc [Link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/store/index.html#!/operations#APICollection#apisGet)). Here is the curl I have used :

```
curl -k -H '{"X-WSO2-Tenant":"xyz.com"}' https://localhost:9443/api/am/store/v0.11/apis
```

Because those are public APIs, I do not need to provide authorization token. It returns APIs from ***carbon.super*** tenant which is default tenant, not the one I created in xyz.com tenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you sent the header is wrong. Please check below.

```
curl -k -H "X-WSO2-Tenant: xyz.com" "https://localhost:9443/api/am/store/v0.11/apis"
```

Comment: My bad. I was sending it like data(-d) with curly brackets. It is working fine now. Thank you.